# Merge some specific files from an old branch to my current branch

Tags: git

I am working on a branch B. I created my branch and checked out from the latest master commit. My colleague worked on a branch A. He checkout a long time ago from master so he's behind it:

```
                           --------- A1
                          /
                         /
                        /
--------- M1 --------- M2 --------- M3 --------- M4 --------- M5 --------- B1
```

In his branch he worked on a lot of files and I only need some of them. Let's call them File1.txt, File2.txt and File3.txt. I would like to merge these files to my branch. My question is: What's the approach to follow in this case? Should I merge/rebase on top of his outdated branch ? Is there a way to just get these 3 files and merge them to my current working branch and get a B2 commit?

Comment: Why not simply merge A1 into B1?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So I just need to checkout to my branch and call `git merge my_colleague_branch` and resolve conflits? That's it?

Comment: Should be, that's how git is meant to work. If your colleague has modified files you *don't* want changes from, that's a different story, but if you just want all the changes from that branch, merge it into your branch and you should be done.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes he did. He modified a lot files and I just need 3 of them.

Comment: Might want to check out the answer left by Marc down below instead then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git checkout --patch <branch> <filename>` to patch already existing files in your current branch by using files from another branch. If the file does not exist in your current branch, use `git checkout <branch> <filename>` to edit it in your branch. Next, you can save the files and commit changes.

In your case (example for file1.txt):

1. Go to branch B with
   `git checkout B`
2. Use `git checkout --patch A file1.txt` or, if the file1.txt does not exist in branch B, use `git checkout A file1.txt`
3. On `Apply this hunk to index and worktree` choose `y`
4. Save the file and `git add file1.txt` and commit  your changes with `git commit -m 'Your commit message'`

Here is a specific description of the `git checkout --patch` taken from [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-p--patchlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203):

```
-p
--patch
Interactively select hunks in the difference between the <tree-ish> (or the index, if unspecified) and the working tree. The chosen hunks are then applied in reverse to the working tree (and if a <tree-ish> was specified, the index).

This means that you can use git checkout -p to selectively discard edits from your current working tree. See the “Interactive Mode” section of git-add[1] to learn how to operate the --patch mode.

Note that this option uses the no overlay mode by default (see also --overlay), and currently doesn’t support overlay mode.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need : the files `File{1,2,3}.txt` as they are in `A1`, discarding all changes introduced on these files during `M2..M4`, just use :

```
git checkout A1 -- File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt
```

If you really need to merge (combine the changes in `A1` with the changes in `M2..M4`), you can create a commit with only these files, and use that commit :

```
# create a branch from A1 :
git branch wip A1
git checkout wip

# replay changes only for the files
git reset HEAD^
git add File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt
git commit
git checkout .  # drop other changes

# use merge or rebase to combine the changes
git rebase M4
```